# SegWit - what is the address I need to deposit to?

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness

I'm using bitcoin core 0.16.0 on **`regtest`** and call getnewaddress
I'm getting  "2N4dpih8KAdfJyXn2vhWixUwmYJ6DBfeRM1"
As I call validateaddress "2N4dpih8KAdfJyXn2vhWixUwmYJ6DBfeRM1" I get:
￼
`{
  "isvalid": true,
  "address": "2N4dpih8KAdfJyXn2vhWixUwmYJ6DBfeRM1",
  "scriptPubKey": "a9147cef86e3cf39b81f5263375b798536f19d4e8d0687",
  "ismine": true,
  "iswatchonly": false,
  "isscript": true,
  "iswitness": false,
  "script": "witness_v0_keyhash",
  "hex": "00147568d37152e5b720780b2e4d2346db97b2af5d8f",
  "pubkey": "0211ea7f9c2f4aba987926365ecbe009788d6ca905231f28828ff301d261cfc06d",
  "embedded": {
    "isscript": false,
    "iswitness": true,
    "witness_version": 0,
    "witness_program": "7568d37152e5b720780b2e4d2346db97b2af5d8f",
    "pubkey": "0211ea7f9c2f4aba987926365ecbe009788d6ca905231f28828ff301d261cfc06d",
    "address": "bcrt1qw45dxu2jukmjq7qt9exjx3kmj7e27hv0umayga",
    "scriptPubKey": "00147568d37152e5b720780b2e4d2346db97b2af5d8f"
  },
  "addresses": [
    "bcrt1qw45dxu2jukmjq7qt9exjx3kmj7e27hv0umayga"
  ],
  "account": "",
  "timestamp": 1517310214,
  "hdkeypath": "m/0'/0'/37'",
  "hdmasterkeyid": "c975977fb41bc2613d6cda5f10b917a2954893ad"
}`

What is the segwit address ? is it the one I got from getnewaddress or "bcrt1qw45dxu2jukmjq7qt9exjx3kmj7e27hv0umayga" inside the "embedded" section with "iswitness" : true ?

So to check this issue I've send to both addresses 2 btc on regtest and decoded the rawtransaction, for 2N4dpih8KAdfJyXn2vhWixUwmYJ6DBfeRM1 tx is:

`{
  "txid": "03a9d0e354d2ab25a5b14d0aa9a7651e7209a61596cd81886a501a6968cfb721",
  "hash": "668ca307cf165b2e5658de7278545ddaad3e071147d41293f60471442a3eddd9",
  "version": 2,
  "size": 247,
  "vsize": 166,
  "locktime": 115,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "cea9f59c19c8dbaf1e2cb253a2980228a45c9658b8b7e48a87288a1d269867f9",
      "vout": 0,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "00142f6c397ad231f08de05da5d0aee634dd5974f75a",
        "hex": "1600142f6c397ad231f08de05da5d0aee634dd5974f75a"
      },
      "txinwitness": [
        "304402201d063a846bc7f8504399d47649e7749e4c6c68070cb2840fb72d1c3f2cc717f302202b0314aea962da5aa056e33e71315ad9f0e4e0501dacc800fee82b70c870e79601",
        "03ecef34be2e1f0a1dc7ec43fa2248cf0d06d85be13c8220aec6bda0d0405c19c2"
      ],
      "sequence": 4294967293
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 4.00029480,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_HASH160 bf181b015a2022e0d2d63c2af8793c0addb117ce OP_EQUAL",
        "hex": "a914bf181b015a2022e0d2d63c2af8793c0addb117ce87",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "scripthash",
        "addresses": [
          "2NAfdvoVHL3XWtiyB4ULkB7sST71ZafEVXg"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 1.00000000,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_HASH160 7cef86e3cf39b81f5263375b798536f19d4e8d06 OP_EQUAL",
        "hex": "a9147cef86e3cf39b81f5263375b798536f19d4e8d0687",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "scripthash",
        "addresses": [
          "2N4dpih8KAdfJyXn2vhWixUwmYJ6DBfeRM1"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}`

and for bcrt1qw45dxu2jukmjq7qt9exjx3kmj7e27hv0umayga tx is:
`{
  "txid": "ed857e7318cca006a7f1f975c65742a1cdddf36e46b6f37b958e402c99da47f5",
  "hash": "ed40689ddf66c293ec9cc2c10fb7bb732c7b4e1e3d48c6ae0cd3644a4cad6b27",
  "version": 2,
  "size": 222,
  "vsize": 141,
  "locktime": 115,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "982bb35cc6057afbe92c75527b6c62b4ec855f4155042ef0fadbf784e1b60267",
      "vout": 0,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "",
        "hex": ""
      },
      "txinwitness": [
        "3044022073995927c65c6dade5b8e141fb5c16095b233e163ce5fa28cd18eeb73f68f45f0220749ec988d670cb04b6aec57c0f43bf8ba67331849ce76c70e92a2c7605bb26bd01",
        "0379cc68acccb4442006844530052f7b5fbfe84e5ebb46a1f509f9fc474be4715c"
      ],
      "sequence": 4294967293
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 29.00024460,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "0 acf33e42618956e6df4e1265d7c44500d0fa3c1e",
        "hex": "0014acf33e42618956e6df4e1265d7c44500d0fa3c1e",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "witness_v0_keyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "bcrt1q4nenusnp39twdh6wzfja03z9qrg050q76nct4r"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 1.00000000,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "0 7568d37152e5b720780b2e4d2346db97b2af5d8f",
        "hex": "00147568d37152e5b720780b2e4d2346db97b2af5d8f",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "witness_v0_keyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "bcrt1qw45dxu2jukmjq7qt9exjx3kmj7e27hv0umayga"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}`
So my understanding is that "bcrt1qw45dxu2jukmjq7qt9exjx3kmj7e27hv0umayga" is the SegWit address cause I see at vout that the tx uses "witness_v0_keyhash" to sign the 1 btc . am I correct ? if so , why do I need to call validateaddress on the legacy address to view it's SegWit address ? What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The address you need to sent to is **2N4dpih8KAdfJyXn2vhWixUwmYJ6DBfeRM1**, as that is the output of `getnewaddress`.

That's a P2SH-P2WPKH address, which became the default in 0.16. It is not a legacy address, but a P2SH-embedded segwit address.

If you want a P2WPKH (native, bech32) address, you should tell `getnewaddress` that is what you want, by calling `getnewaddress "" "bech32"`. Alternatively, you can tell `bitcoind` that you always want by putting `addresstype=bech32` in `bitcoin.conf`.

Never try to convert one address type into another yourself. `validateaddress` is giving you information about the address you passed in. `bitcoind` does not expect payments to anything but the address that `getnewaddress` gave you.

Comment: Will i need to use bech32 at some point in the future adoption of segwit ?

Comment: If you like. No reason why you have to. It's just a bit cheaper for you if you do (as spending transactions will have lower weight).

Comment: @PieterWuille Did you mean using bech32 addresses we pay less tx fees?

Comment: Yes, if you **receive** coins using bech32 addresses (as in: you're giving bech32 addresses to others who pay you), it will (over time) become cheaper for you to send coins. The difference for typical transactions is around 20%.